# CMake shared library on Windows: error when creating dll

Tags: windows, cmake, shared-libraries

Using CMake (version 3.13.2) to build a shared C library on Windows with MSVC compiler (version 19.16.27025.1).
I get the following error:

```
Erreur  MSB3073 La commande "setlocal
cd "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E __create_def "//vmware- 
host/Shared 
Folders/Documents/funnel/build/getopt/getopt.dir/Debug/exports.def" 
"//vmware-host/Shared 
Folders/Documents/funnel/build/getopt/getopt.dir/Debug//objects.txt"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" s'est arrêtée avec le code 1.
```

Some excerpts of the `CMakeLists.txt` files defining the build options:

```
# CMakeLists.txt in root
add_compile_options(/Wall /c)
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)
add_subdirectory(getopt)

# CMakeLists.txt in root/getopt
set(src_files getopt.c getopt1.c)
set(hdr_files ansidecl.h getopt.h)
add_library(getopt SHARED "${src_files}" "${hdr_files}")
```

(Building `STATIC` library on Windows is OK. Building `SHARED` library on Linux with `gcc` is OK.)

-- **EDIT** (answering vre's comment) --

Running `set_target_properties` before call to `add_library` yields the following error.

```
set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to: getopt
```

Running `cmake` with the proposed generator yields the following (probably because the compiler is not installed on my system though it is proposed in the list returned by `cmake -H`: installing this version would help?).

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17763.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
```

Running `cmake --build [...]` from console (having previously generated the build system with `Visual Studio 15 2017`) yields the following error.

```
"\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (cible par défaut) (1) ->
"\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\src\exe.vcxproj" (cible par défaut) (3) ->
"\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt\getopt.vcxproj" (cible par défaut) (4) ->
(PreLinkEvent cible) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(13
3,5): error MSB3073: La commande "setlocal [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt\getopt.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,
5): error MSB3073: cd "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt" [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Docume
nts\funnel\build\getopt\getopt.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,
5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt\getopt
.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,
5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E __create_def "//vmware-host/Shared Folders/Documents/funne
l/build/getopt/getopt.dir/Release/exports.def" "//vmware-host/Shared Folders/Documents/funnel/build/getopt/getopt.dir/R
elease//objects.txt" [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt\getopt.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,
5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt\getopt
.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,
5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt\getopt.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,
5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\fu
nnel\build\getopt\getopt.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,
5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt\getopt.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,
5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt\getopt.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,
5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt\getopt.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,
5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt\getopt
.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,
5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" s'est arrêtée avec le code 1. [\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\funnel\build\getopt\ge
topt.vcxproj]
```

Comment: Try adding `set_target_properties(getopt PROPERTIES WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS 1)` before your call to `add_library`. If you do not succeed please run `cmake -H. -B<your_builddir> -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" ` followed by `cmake --build <your_builddir> --target ALL_BUILD --config Release` from your sourcedir and add the console output to your post. The errors you added are from a Visual Studio output window and do not show the reason of failure.

Comment: Why the `/c` option in `add_compile_options(/Wall /c)`? Adding `/c` puts it into compile only mode. CMake and MSBuild will control `/c` as appropriate but forcing it can probably break the creation of the necessary files and linking steps when building a DLL.

Comment: `cmake --help` lists all the generators it knows how to create projects for not what you have installed.  You need to pick the correct one for your system.

Comment: `/c` option is used to build another Object library in the project. I acknowledge  that it must be redundant with the `ÒBJECT` option of `add_library`. Indeed supressing `/c` compile options does not change anything. The error persists.

Comment: I think I know where the issue comes from. I run `cmake` from a virtual machine. The source directory is on the file system of the host and mounted as a network drive on the virtual machine. Somehow it does not cause any problem when building static libraries but it does in the case of shared ones. Relocating the source directory on the file system of the virtual machine eliminates the error.

Comment: Pardon me, I meant to add `set_target_properties(getopt PROPERTIES WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS 1)` after the add_library call. A target **must** exist before properties can be set.